# Spark MLlib: PCA on 9570 columns takes too long

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pca, ram

1) I am doing a PCA on 9570 columns giving it 12288 mb RAM in local mode(which means driver only) and it takes from 1.5 hours up to 2. This is the code (very simple):

```
System.out.println("level1\n");
VectorAssembler assemblerexp = new VectorAssembler()
       .setInputCols(metincols)
       .setOutputCol("intensity");
expoutput = assemblerexp.transform(expavgpeaks);

System.out.println("level2\n");
PCAModel pcaexp = new PCA()
       .setInputCol("intensity")
       .setOutputCol("pcaFeatures")
       .setK(2)
       .fit(expoutput);

System.out.println("level3\n");
```

So the time that it takes to print level3 is what it takes long (1.5 to 2 hours). Is it normal that it takes so long? I have tried different number partitions (2,4,6,8,50,500,10000) and for some of them also takes almost 2 hours while for others I get a Java heap space error. Also some pictures from Spark User Interface:

> [Executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdscI.png) [Jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwKRF.png) [Stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czc7m.png) [environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHGrN.png)

2) Is it also normal that I get different results with the PCA every time?

Comment: 12TB of memory?

Comment: ops..my bad..12288m..edited it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting RAM programmatically, it does not take effect, and a proper way would be to provide JVM arguments.

Comment: Ok, after some time going back to this. Having defined the java memory correctly from netbeans environment still takes a lot of time. Also, I persist the vector before PCA and I get an error: failed to compile: org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException: Compiling "GeneratedClass": Code of method "processNext()V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4" grows beyond 64 KB But the program continues to execute! Any ideas of what this may be?

Comment: Try `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage", "false")` and `spark.conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "5g")`